# Why does my code stop after calling the first function?

Tags: python, function, while-loop

So far my unfinished code is running as expected, but after i enter "Y" on "suggestion" inside
"def inside_cart()",  it will run "def ordering()" but it will not proceed to "def inside_cart" again.

This is my code

---

```
print("(1)Home")
print("- - - - - Welcome to BSITEA - - - - -")
print("\n")
food =["Burger","Fries","Hotdog","Sundae","Coke Float"]
price =[15,10,20,30,50]
cart =[]
cost =[]
counter = 0
def menu():
    print("- - - - - Menu - - - - -\n")
    collection = [["\nCode","  Description","     Size","   Price"],
                  ["  1","      Borgar","      Medium","  15"],
                  ["  2","      Fries","       Medium","  10"],
                  ["  3","      Hotdog","      Medium","  20"],
                  ["  4","      Sundae","      Medium","  30"],
                  ["  5","      Coke Float","  Medium","  50"]]

    for a in collection:
        for b in a:
            print(b,end=' ')
        print()
menu()
first = True
def ordering():
  print("\nPlease select the CODE of the food you want to order")
  while first==True:
    
    global counter
    #burger
    order = input("Type the code you want to order: \n")
    if order == ("1"):
      print("You have selected \n")
      print(food[0])
      cart.append(food[0])
      cost.append(price[0])
      counter= counter + 15
      try_again = input("\nWould you like to add more? (Y/N) ")
      if try_again == "n" or try_again == "N":
          break
      else:
        print(" ")
    #fries
    elif order == ("2"):
      print("You have selected \n")
      print(food[1])
      cart.append(food[1])
      cost.append(price[1])
      counter= counter + 10
      try_again = input("\nWould you like to add more? (Y/N) ").lower()
      if try_again != ("y"):
          break
    #hotdog
    elif order == ("3"):
      print("You have selected \n")
      print(food[2])
      cart.append(food[2])
      cost.append(price[2])
      counter= counter + 20
      try_again = input("\nWould you like to add more? (Y/N) ").lower()
      if try_again != ("y"):
          break
   #sundae
    elif order == ("4"):
      print("You have selected \n")
      print(food[3])
      cart.append(food[3])
      cost.append(price[3])
      counter= counter + 30
      try_again = input("\nWould you like to add more? (Y/N) ").lower()
      if try_again != ("y"):
          break
  #coke float
    elif order == ("5"):
      print("You have selected \n")
      print(food[4])
      cart.append(food[4])
      cost.append(price[4])
      counter= counter + 50
      try_again = input("\nWould you like to add more? (Y/N) ").lower()
      if try_again != ("y"):
          break
 
    else:
      print("\nInvalid input. Please put only the CODE of the item\n")
ordering()

def inside_cart():
  while first == True:
    print(' ')
    print(' ')
    print("The inside of your cart are currently")
    print(cart)
    print(cost)
    print(counter, " Pesos")
  
    suggestion = input("would you like to order more? Y/N: ")
    if suggestion == "y" or suggestion == "Y":
      ordering()
    else:
      print("test")
    break
inside_cart()
```

> The expected output is that i should be able to trigger "def inside_cart" again but it only show a blank line

Comment: The `break` is wrongly indented... It will happen after the `if`. Did you mean it to be under the `else`?

Comment: to be completely honest i don't know which "break" you are referring to

Comment: The last one... After `print("test")`

Comment: i see. that was the problem, thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

after running "ordering()" in the "inside_cart()", there is nothing left for the code to do except "break"

i suggest removing the else statement inside the "inside_cart()"

or run "inside_cart()" again after done "ordering()"

```
def inside_cart():
  while first == True:
    print(' ')
    print(' ')
    print("The inside of your cart are currently")
    print(cart)
    print(cost)
    print(counter, " Pesos")

    suggestion = input("would you like to order more? Y/N: ")
    if suggestion == "y" or suggestion == "Y":
      ordering()
      inside_cart()
    else:
      print("test")
    break
inside_cart()
```

Comment: Why even have the `while` loop if you're calling the function recursively? It should be one or the other

Comment: yes i thought about it after posting the code . it can be removed.

Comment: As i stated earlier, the code is still unfinished and i happened to come across that problem. I will take into consideration removing the  `while ` loop if i find it not usable